# Universal links support for TestFlight apps

Tags: deep-linking, testflight, ios-universal-links, react-native-deep-linking, testflight-public-link

I have an app in TestFlight right now, and it's not ready to go public. I'm willing to add universal links to it, so I can invite my testers to test the app via a universal link which holds a few parameters.

The flow would be:
`Generate a universal link with specific invitation params -> User taps on the link -> if TestFlight is not installed it will go download TestFlight -> then will go to download the app from TestFlight -> Then will run the app and pass the params`

I have tried to validate the do-ability of this, but couldn't find any helping articles about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very doable.

1. Within the [apps menu](https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/apps) of appstoreconnect, select your application that you want to share via TestFlight.
2. From the App page select the TestFlight menu option in the second menu.
3. You'll find the `External Testing` menu item in the left side menu and click the blue plus button to add a new group.
4. Submit a build of your application to that group for review by Apple
5. Upon app review approval you'll be able to generate a link from this same page that will allow anyone who accesses this link to join that group and test your application within test flight.
   [image]

Edit: Not sure exactly what you mean by `a universal link which holds a few parameters`... so I hope this is still helpful